# how to highlight color when insearch but not press the "enter" key

Tags: vim

While when I search in my files, I type  "com" and the foreground of word "comment" will display as white. When I press "enter" key, the word's foreground will change to "orange".

`hi Search term=standout ctermfg=4 ctermbg=3` only take effect when i press the "enter" key.

Is there some option can change the color when i didn't press the "enter" key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlight group that you're looking for is `IncSearch` (incremental search). You can use the following definition

```
hi IncSearch ctermfg=4 ctermbg=3
```